# JavaFX split space evenly between two side panels in an HBox

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have an HBox that contains a square VBox in the center. The HBox width can be made larger than it's height, leaving extra space on the sides. I want to fill this extra space on the left and right with separate VBoxes where I will put buttons, info, etc. I want these two VBoxes, the "side panels," to always be of equal width. However, as you can see from the image below, when the right panel has a button and the left does not, it is wider than the left panel:
[image]

I thought

```
rightPanel.minWidthProperty().bindBidirectional(leftPanel.minWidthProperty());
rightPanel.prefWidthProperty().bindBidirectional(leftPanel.prefWidthProperty());
```

would do the trick, but it didn't.

Here's my code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.NumberBinding;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.layout.Border;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderStroke;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderStrokeStyle;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderWidths;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class FX010 extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        GamePanel gp = new GamePanel();
        Scene scene = new Scene(gp, 800, 600);

        primaryStage.setTitle("testing");
        primaryStage.minWidthProperty().bind(primaryStage.heightProperty());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public class GamePanel extends HBox{
        public GamePanel() {
            this.setMinHeight(400);
            final VBox boardBox = new VBox();

            boardBox.alignmentProperty().set(Pos.CENTER);
            this.alignmentProperty().set(Pos.CENTER);


            VBox leftPanel, rightPanel;
            leftPanel = new VBox();
            rightPanel = new VBox();
            leftPanel.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.DARKRED, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID,
                    CornerRadii.EMPTY,new BorderWidths(1))));
            rightPanel.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.DARKRED, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID,
                    CornerRadii.EMPTY,new BorderWidths(1))));
            rightPanel.minWidthProperty().bindBidirectional(leftPanel.minWidthProperty());
            rightPanel.prefWidthProperty().bindBidirectional(leftPanel.prefWidthProperty());
            rightPanel.getChildren().add(new Button("testtesttest"));

            HBox.setHgrow(leftPanel, Priority.ALWAYS);
            HBox.setHgrow(rightPanel, Priority.ALWAYS);

            StackPane board = new StackPane(new Rectangle(100,100,Color.RED));
            board.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.DARKBLUE, BorderStrokeStyle.DASHED,
                    CornerRadii.EMPTY,new BorderWidths(1))));

            final NumberBinding binding = Bindings.min(widthProperty(), heightProperty());

            boardBox.prefWidthProperty().bind(binding);
            boardBox.prefHeightProperty().bind(binding);
            boardBox.setMaxSize(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);

            VBox.setVgrow(board, Priority.ALWAYS);

            boardBox.getChildren().add(board);

            getChildren().addAll(leftPanel, boardBox, rightPanel);

            //HBox.setHgrow(this, Priority.ALWAYS);
        }
    }
}
```

**How can I force `leftPanel` to always have the same width as `rightPanel`, while still ensuring that `boardBox` is always a square?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing, I got this to work:

```
public class GamePanel extends HBox{
        Pane leftPanel, rightPanel, iLeft, iRight;
        VBox boardBox;
        public GamePanel() {
            this.setMinHeight(400);
            iLeft = new Pane();
            boardBox = new VBox();
            iRight = new Pane();

            boardBox.alignmentProperty().set(Pos.CENTER);
            this.alignmentProperty().set(Pos.CENTER);

            leftPanel = new Pane();
            rightPanel = new Pane();
            leftPanel.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.DARKRED, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID,
                    CornerRadii.EMPTY,new BorderWidths(1))));
            rightPanel.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.DARKRED, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID,
                    CornerRadii.EMPTY,new BorderWidths(1))));
            rightPanel.setPrefWidth(0);
            leftPanel.setPrefWidth(0);
            iRight.getChildren().add(new Button("testtesttest"));
            rightPanel.getChildren().add(iRight);

            HBox.setHgrow(leftPanel, Priority.ALWAYS);
            HBox.setHgrow(rightPanel, Priority.ALWAYS);


            StackPane board = new StackPane(new Rectangle(100,100,Color.RED));
            board.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.DARKBLUE, BorderStrokeStyle.DASHED,
                    CornerRadii.EMPTY,new BorderWidths(1))));

            final NumberBinding binding = Bindings.min(widthProperty(), heightProperty());

            boardBox.prefWidthProperty().bind(binding);
            boardBox.prefHeightProperty().bind(binding);
            boardBox.setMaxSize(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);

            VBox.setVgrow(board, Priority.ALWAYS);

            boardBox.getChildren().add(board);

            getChildren().addAll(leftPanel, boardBox, rightPanel);

            //HBox.setHgrow(this, Priority.ALWAYS);
        }
    }
```

This solution involves setting the left and right panel's `prefWidth` to zero, then adding internal panes into each panel, which the content is then added to. I think the reason that this works is because space is allocated for the prefWidth before the panel's size is expanded by the Hgrow constraint. Since equal amounts of space are added to each panel by the HBox, the panel with a greater prefWidth ends up bigger. By setting both to zero, they both start with no prefWidth and thus end up at the same size. I believe that's also why [anko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62031335/11788023) seemed to work - because when they start with equal prefWidths and the same amount of space is added to each, they end up with the same size. However, setting a prefWidth of 100 messes with the `boardBox`'s size (makes it not a square) when the stage's width is shrunk as small as possible.

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, and I'd be happy to accept a better answer.

Comment: Don't you know, only the devil himself would dare to set a value for prefered width. :) Just kidding. If 0 works better than the exemplary 100, I am fine with it. Good job.

Comment: @anko Hard-coded sizes are the antithesis to responsive design. Here it seems Sam is using nested layouts to "trick" the system. Unfortunately, a more robust solution would probably involve creating a custom layout.

Answer (score 0):

It works when you add e. g.:

```
leftPanel.setPrefWidth(100d);
rightPanel.setPrefWidth(100d);
```

Edit: Maybe it would be better if you use a `GridPane` as a root layout where you can  have three columns with a fixed percentage width like e. g.: 15 % (left-hand side), 70 % (center) and 15 % (right-hand side). But only you can know and decide what fits best for your project. :-P

Comment: Thank you, but I do not follow any religious belivies of good and evil or any other dogmas ;) Feel free to provide a better answer.

Comment: nothing religious in marking a bad answer ;) this will break if dimensions change for whatever reasons

Comment: So what would be a god answer then?